# 'This is a great comment' - why this hint?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

Did You ever refrain from clicking 'This is a great comment' just becase you think that it is not that great, but you still find it valuable? I think that if this hint was 'this is useful comment', I would click it more. Do you have this feeling too or is it just me?

Comment: Seems pedantic.

Comment: @snicker: I thought your comment was great, though not particularly useful. Luckily under the current verbiage guidelines, that justified my upvote of it.

Comment: Wait, the only requirement for upvoting a comment is that it be great?  How do you jerks justify it when you don't upvote every single comment I make?  I'm weaving straw into gold for you ingrates.

Comment: @Pesto: I'm **so** not upvoting that.

Comment: @LukLed: For what it's worth, based on the votes on this question at least two people agreed with you, and at least two didn't. I didn't feel strongly enough about it one way or the other to bother voting. Welcome to Meta.

Comment: @John: I thought your comment was great, though not particularly useful. Luckily under the current verbiage guidelines, that justified my upvote of it.

Comment: @snicker: +1 for retweeting, I mean blatant plagiarism. :)

Comment: @John: Was the title changed to "this is a plagiarized comment"? It still reads "This comment is OUTSTANDING!" to me (Greasemonkey script)

Comment: @snicker: +1 for the greasemonkey solution. Now I can finally go to sleep calm: "This comment was useful".

Comment: +1 "this question is useful and clear" :)

Comment: "you should upvote this comment, you should upvote this comment" (Greasemonkey script)

Answer (score 5):

The verbiage : `This is a Great Comment` is used because `+1 Insightful`, `+1 Funny`, `+1 Interesting` were taken.

Comment: I gotta give some upvote love for /.

Comment: If it was a comment, I could give +1 for Funny, but the hint on upvoting says 'This answer is useful'...

Comment: +1 Useful couldn't possibly exist in `/.`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced that we need to soften that language. If the language makes you not want to click, then I say don't. I don't know that we need to encourage zillions of comment upvotes unnecessarily.

In other words, if you think the comment is great, click it. If you don't, don't. If you feel the comment is useful, but not quite up to great standards, but you still want to click it ... Go right ahead. Not gonna hurt anybody in any event. :)

And who knows, your vote might the one which pushes someone into a Pundit badge.

Comment: I didn't ask to soften language. I asked if your feelings are similar:) It seems that they are not:)

Comment: Fair 'nuff. But since that comment's not great, I totally can't upvote it ... :) (Sorry, now *I'm* being pedantic. It's Friday afternoon; none of this is personal. :) )

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply the same logic to the upvote and downvote buttons. Sometimes I want to upvote an answer, but It's not useful but it's something else :P